# Numpy Conversion Inequality

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

So I have a one-dimensional int64 numpy array `array1` with `np.unique(array1)` giving me `[0 1 7 8]` values.

I converted `array1` to a uint8 image array `array2` as follows: `array2 = (array1 * 50).astype(np.uint8)`. The multiplier 50 was so that I could visualize my output at the very least, given that unique pixel values [0 1 7 8] are too small a value.

Now, when I tried to retrieve `array1` as follows:

```
    [1] recon_array1 = array2.astype(np.int64)/50
    [2] recon_array1 = recon_array1.astype(np.int64)
```

And perform `np.unique(recon_array1)`, it actually gives me `[0 1 2]`. I think this is because of the multiple conversions, like for instance [1] actually gives me a `dtype = float64` with unique values `[0 1 1.88 2.88]`. Hence, recognizing this and converting it to int64 like in [2], the output `[0 1 2]` made sense.

My goal eventually is to retrieve the original `array1` with unique values `[0 1 7 8]`. Can someone please point out my mistake? Is retrieving `array1` still even possible and what kind of conversion processing should be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the unit8 conversion, when you perform this conversion what you get is the result of this operation: `x%256` so you divide your number by 256 and keep the rest.

I wouldn't know how to do the reverse process because:

```
In [35]: 350%256 # (7*50).uint8
Out[35]: 94

In [36]: 1630%256 
Out[36]: 94
```

So actually with just the result of the values of the array2 is impossible to know whether it is 350 or 1630 or any other `n*256+94` with n = {1,...n}

Hope it helps...

### Suggestion

For creating the image instead of using uint8 you can create a map (0,255) so the greatest value of your array is 255 and the smaller 0, in that way you can do the reverse calculation.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([0, 1, 7, 8])

fn = lambda x: x*255/max(array1)

invfn = lambda x: x*max(array1)/255

array2 = fn(array1)

recon_array1 = (invfn(array2)).astype(np.int64)
recon_array1 = recon_array1.astype(np.int64)
```